# Line-through input value, but not placeholder

Tags: css

I got a html input, and want to add a

`text-decoration: line-through;`

to the value (if validation fails, which sets a specific css class).

I don't want that to appear on the placeholder though, which I tried to fix by adding a

```
input::placeholder {
   text-decoration: none; 
}
```

Unfortunately that doesn't work.
Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: I tested it in an empty project. It works. 
It must be a specificity problem or a wrong selector in your project. Could you share a bigger piece of your code?

Comment: @KaptainIglo actually it already works as is but only in Firefox. It doesn't in Chrome.. and that's why `:placeholder-shown` comes into play. It will style the actual `input` element instead of the placeholder text. It's a confusing shade I agree.. but the answer given correctly addressed the issue so that it will work everywhere as expected

Comment: I actually tested on Firefox, and it worked :D but good to know about place-holder shown, thanks for sharing.

Comment: @KaptainIglo for the sake of records at first writing I mixed the two browsers in my sentence and it was eveyrthing flipped. I corrected the mistake

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `:not(:placeholder-shown)` to exclude the case when you have the placeholder

```css
input.error:not(:placeholder-shown) {
  text-decoration: line-through;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="example" class="error">

<input type="text" placeholder="example">
```

Comment: Works flawlessly, thanks!